# Finding the URL of InfoPath View

Tags: infopath, list-view

I've set up a InfoPath 2013 form with a number of different view. The form will be filled in in stages. So what I want to happen is that once a view of the form has been filled in and submitted then when that has been approved that the approver can send out a link to the next stage. Any suggestions? How would I get the URL for the form view? Any help appreciated!

Comment: You can insert a HyperLink in the email body. The URL should be like this:
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TWLN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TWLN.png) reference: https://olenicksharepoint.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/add-a-link-to-a-list-item-in-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow-email/

Comment: Thanks, would that take me to the specific View?

Comment: Add this to go to a specific view: &DefaultView=yourFormView (View name is case sensitive!)

Comment: Cheers that worked!